# External script in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, zoho

I am trying to add a Zoho Campaign Newsletter Form to my Gatsby site.
I added the code to gatsby-ssr.js inside the setHeadComponents but when starting gatsby -> its not working... 
I am not sure why because when i try the code in the browser console it's working fine. Looks like its not loaded or defined. I am new to JS and Gatsby so maybe you can help me here.

here is my code:

```
setHeadComponents([
 <script 
        type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://sfcp.maillist-manage.eu/js/optin.min.js" 
        key="newsletter"
        defer={true}
    />,
    <script 
        type="text/javascript"
        key="newsletter-start"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            try {
                  function startsf() {
                    setupSF('###############','ZCFORMVIEW',false,'light',false,'0');
                  }  

                  window.onload = startsf;
                }
                catch (error) {console.log(error)}
            `}}
    />,
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to is to place your scripts inside `<Helmet>` tag in any desired component or layout For example, in `index.js` file something like this:

```
    import React from "react"
    import Helmet from "react-helmet"

    import Layout from "../components/layout"
    import SEO from "../components/seo"

    const IndexPage = () => (
        <Layout>
          <SEO title="Live" />
          <Helmet>
            <script src="https://sfcp.maillist-manage.eu/js/optin.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script 
        type="text/javascript"
        key="newsletter-start"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            try {
                  function startsf() {
                    setupSF('###############','ZCFORMVIEW',false,'light',false,'0');
                  }  

                  window.onload = startsf;
                }
                catch (error) {console.log(error)}
            `}}
    />
          </Helmet>
        </Layout>
    )
```

You can check for further information about [Gatsby's Helmet](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/), and [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet), but basically, `<Helmet>` component allows you to insert a few code that will be placed after compilation inside the `<head>` tag.

**Edit**: I've tested it in my local machine and it works, as the following screenshot shows:

[image: Load of external scripts with status 200]