# How to use the Adobe Embed API in GatsbyJS

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to use the Adobe Embed API for my website. I'm using GatsbyJS and I don't know how to include it in my Gatbsy File. The following is what I'm trying to include, but since I'm not using any .html file, how do I include this in my code?

```
<script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function(){ 
        var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>"});
        adobeDCView.previewFile({
            content:{promise: "<FILE_BLOB_PROMISE>"},
            metaData:{fileName: "<FILE_NAME>"}
        }, {embedMode: "LIGHT_BOX"});
    });
</script>
```

Update:
Now I have this in one of my file:

```
<Helmet>
      <script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function(){ 
      useEffect(() => {
        var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "<CLIENT_ID>"});
        adobeDCView.previewFile({
        content:{location: {url: "https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view- 
        sdk-demo/PDFs/Bodea Brochure.pdf"}},  
        metaData:{fileName: "Bodea.pdf"}
  }, {embedMode: "LIGHT_BOX"});}
  )});
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

and it's saying AdobeDC isn't defined, I'm very new and where did it go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use any HTML file but in the end, Gatsby builds your HTML.

You have many ways of including an external script in your source. In your case, the most straightforward way is to [customize the HTML](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/).

Run:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

Or manually copy the `default-html.js` from `.cache` folder, place it in `/src` and rename the file to `html.js`.

Once done, if when building the site, Gatsby finds the `html.js` inside `/src`, it will use it as a boilerplate of your code, so adding the Adobe snippet there should work for you:

```
export default function HTML(props) {
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
      </head>
      <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {/* Add your scripts here */}
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Other methods of adding third-party scripts:

- [External script in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827803/external-script-in-gatsby)
- [Add Script tag in Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61877792/add-script-tag-in-gatsby)
- [How to load script in specific page in gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235074/how-to-load-script-in-specific-page-in-gatsby/64237572#64237572)
- [Gatsby site, Script not available on first page request with Helmet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480486/gatsby-site-script-not-available-on-first-page-request-with-helmet/69480849#69480849)

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but would modifying html.js alter all my pages, no? If so then it'd be better to use <Helmet>? Sorry I'm very new to Gatsby

Comment: Yes it will, but your script will only be inserted once, unlike if you do with `Helmet` (because of the rehydration), where it will be inserted each time the page renders

Comment: I've tried this but it somehow didn't work. When I filled it it gives errors so I tried using useEffect, but it still doesn't show up in my page. Also, if it is modifying all my pages, can I restrict it to just shows up in one of my pages?

Comment: You will need to use Helmet approach rather than the `html.js`. Without seeing the code you tried and the result it's impossible to guess what's going on.

Comment: I updated the code where it still doesn't work, I have no idea why AdobeDC isn't defined